# Logistic Regression - Continuous dependent variable SAS

Tags: sas

Trying to conduct a few analyses on my dataset with my dependent variable as continuous. For the linear regression I planned to conduct an ANCOVA through proc surveyreg, but I was confused regarding what I should do for logistic regression (looking for OR). Fairly new to SAS and I understand that prog log requires a categorical variable for its dependent variable. Curious as to if you all had any insight as to other programs that may assist me in this endeavor. Regarding my variables, I am evaluating Depression Score Totals (0-27) against Physical Function scores (0-27), BMI, Gender, Age (in years), and frequency of hospital visitation. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Is your continuous variable coded as numeric and you just need it as a category? Logistic regression is for discrete values only (e.g. categories or binary variables)

Comment: sounds like a general linear model.  Look at proc GLM